# How does the launch of a Polar Satellite differ from that of an East-West orbiter?

Tags: launch

A polar satellite orbits a planet over it's poles.

An East/West orbiter (I couldn't find the term for such satellites) may orbit anywhere from LEO up as high as GEO.

How does the launch process (for want of a better word) differ other than that the former launches southward, and the latter eastward? *Is* there a difference?

Comment: Are you referring to [retrograde orbits](http://space.stackexchange.com/q/810/49)?

Comment: Both retrograde, and regular. I didn't want to put 'East-West', and 'West-East' together up there (+: It could be confusing.

Comment: Gotcha. So in essence [non-inclined orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-inclined_orbit) and [near-equatorial orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Near_equatorial_orbit), or putting it otherwise, [box orbits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_orbit) whose ground track doesn't cross the north-south pole boundaries. I'm not sure there's a single name for them, short of saying "non-polar orbits". :|

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key difference is that you don't get any rotational assistance from the Earth for a North-South launch if you try a direct launch into orbit.

In practice this means North-South orbits seem to be launched at a relatively steep angle to the North or South while still getting some of the Earth's rotation boost and then using thrust when in orbit to change from a steep angle to a North-South orbit.

Haven't managed to find figures on optimum launch direction - will update as I find them.

Comment: Also, since you gain no advantage from the Earth's rotation, you can launch from pads at notherly latitudes, which is very convenient for countries far from the equator.

Comment: @user6244 High latitudes (not just North, but also South). Then again, this is true for any latitudes, including equatorial. ;)

Comment: If your target orbit is polar, your equatorial rotation is a burden rather than a benefit - launching closer to the poles becomes the more efficient option for polar flights, since there is less influence from Earth's rotation that must be canceled.